# Twitter Bootstrap tooltip not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap

I thought this would be simple enough but somethings wrong. The only Bootstrap gem im using is the [simple form one](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap).

I have the following html:

**app/views/users/new.html.erb**

```
<div id="hint">hint</div>
```

And then in my **application.js** file for javascript I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.

$("#hint").popover({
    title: 'A title!',
    content: 'Some content!'
})
```

In the [Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip Instructions](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) it says to just put this:

```
$('#example').tooltip(options)
```

But I'm not getting anything. How do I use this?

---

**ANSWER**

I had to do this to get it to work:

```
<div id="hint">
  <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="some content">hint</a>
</div>

jQuery( function($) {
    $("#hint a").tooltip()
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem once, and found that if I moved my `$(example).tooltip()` statement from the bottom of my .js file to the top, it started working. I never did figure out what is was about the JavaScript in the file that made the tooltip not work.

BTW, I am confused. Are you doing a tooltip or a popover? If it is a tooltip, you should have a link element, like this

```
<div id="hint"><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="some content">hint</a></div>
```

in your HTML and then

```
$("#hint a").tooltip()
```

in your JavaScript.